# Real-Time Cloning and Partitioning of a Table in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm working with Google BigQuery and facing a challenge in maintaining a real-time, partitioned version of an existing table without incurring the costs associated with scheduled queries. My goal is to clone a table and apply a new partition scheme to it simultaneously, ideally in a single operation or a seamless process that mimics real-time replication.

Here's what I attempted, hoping to clone and partition in one step, but it didn't work

```sql
CREATE TABLE `temp.tables.Call2`
CLONE `temp.tables.Call`
PARTITION BY (DATE_TRUNC(LastModification, DAY));
```

This approach didn't succeed because it seems BigQuery doesn't support adding a `PARTITION BY` clause directly in a `CREATE TABLE ... CLONE` statement.

Is there a native BigQuery feature or combination of features that can achieve this?
Any guidance, examples, or pointers to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery does not allow adding or changing the clustering/partitioning strategy of a table once it already exists, even if you try to "create or replace" the table.

I've had a similar situation where I wanted to take an already-existing streaming table and add partitioning to it (permanently).
If this scenario is similar to what you currently need, the simplest solution I found was to:

1. `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE my_copy_table PARTITION BY ... AS SELECT * FROM my_table`
2. `DROP TABLE my_table`
3. `ALTER TABLE my_copy_table RENAME TO my_table`

So basically we are creating a copy of our table, but with the required partitioning. Then, we drop the original table and rename our copied table to the original name.

This will work in case you have no issues with adding the paritioning on top of your existing table.

See the documentation for creating a partitioned table based on a query result for more information about the partitioning:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#create_a_partitioned_table_from_a_query_result

If this solution does not work for you, please provide more information about the goal, and I will try to help with that as well

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I need a real-time solution. The current solution only works with scheduled queries, which is costly.

Comment: You're still not providing enough information for us to understand the requirements. Do you have a single table that you need to transform? Are tables created continuously? What's the situation that requires a "real time" solution?